# How to say "to look in the mirror"

Tags: set-phrases

What Japanese expression is equivalent to "to look in the mirror"? Is it as simple as 鏡を見る or 鏡に見る?

Comment: 鏡を見る seems fine to me.

Comment: @mackygoo Does 鏡を見る also mean looking in the [metaphorical mirror](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11807/where-does-look-yourself-in-the-mirror-come-from) in Japanese? I'm not sure if this question meant it or actually looking in a real mirror

Comment: @siikamiika I visited the site and read Where does “Look yourself in the mirror” come from?. Yes, 鏡を見る has some nuance of metaphorical meaning, but usually the phrase is used to express the simple action. To tell you the truth, I recalled the phrase 他人｛ひと｝の振り見てわが振り直せ/他人｛ひと｝の振り見てわが身をただす/, when I read the mirror's phrase.

Comment: @mackygoo Thanks, I didn't know that. These comments already contain more than "yes, that's correct" so I think they are worth an answer

Comment: 鏡を見る is fine as is commented by stack reader. 鏡に見る is used as **鏡に**映｛うつ｝る自分｛じぶん｝の姿｛すがた｝を**見る** *I see my reflection in the mirror*.

Answer (score 1):

For "look in the mirror" in the metaphorical sense "reflect on one's own conduct" (with the implication that one will recognise one's wrongdoing and resolve to behave better) how about  反省する (はんせいする) ?